# Как получить данные в форму запросом из той же формы?

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Вопрос заключается в том, что я не могу сделать выборку на форму. Это должно выглядеть примерно следующим образом, например, когда выбираю город, на следующей строчке он должен выводить список улиц. соответственно, это уже находится в форме. Как мне передать GET[..], когда я уже нахожусь в форме, а форма передает данные на совсем другой .php файл? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы не перезагружать страницу только javascript + ajax

запомните и поймите, пхп выполняется на СЕРВЕРЕ клиенту выдается результат выполнения пхп скрипта на сервере, javascript на стороне клиента.

почитайте вот это: [Создаём зависимые списки с помощью jQuery и AJAX](http://xandeadx.ru/blog/javascript/36)
там как раз по вашей теме...

Comment: Дело в том, что я новичок в программировании, мало сталкивался с явой, но я понимаю, что, хочу я того или нет, мне придется писать и на яве... но сейчас мне позарез нужно получить результат, а я на яве не "бум-бум"... мне стыдно так говорить...но, другого выхода не вижу

Comment: @tagir не путай JS и Java а то читать больно. :)

Comment: @tagir почитайте вот [это](http://xandeadx.ru/blog/javascript/36)

Comment: ну а базу всего этого вам придется самостоятельно искать ;)

Comment: вот это точно по моей теме... к сожалению, у меня не хватает "очков" для того, чтобы поставить Вам плюс!(( Благодарю от всей души))

Comment: да ничего, пользуйтесь)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть Вы имеете в виду [ajax](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)?

Comment: может быть...